# React server is not running through npm start

Tags: reactjs

Good Evening I am doing a project in ReactJs through npm start project is compiling but has not started, loading for several minutes via localhost 3000 on google chrome. what should I do now?

Comment: Please provide more information, how did you setup your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Yarn using `yarn install` after that run following command

```
yarn start
```